# Play at the game or Play in the game?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

When I want to ask 
"Which country is playing against ~random country name~ *at/or/in* today's game?"

, which one is the right preposition to use, at or in ?

- Also, does simply saying 'is playing' (without 'against' after that)mean the same thimg?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer to your question is **in**.

Typically **at** would precede the name of the stadium, as in:

> Side A are playing (against) side B **at** the New Stadium **in** today's game/match.

In this context the preposition **against** is optional and is frequently omitted.

https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/play-someone-instead-of-play-with-someone-or-play-against-someone-in-sports.3496584/